# Firemonkey with Memo Classes and Landscape orientation for Android

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

There are many demonstration units provided by both Embarcadero and other third parties for auto-scrolling on showing the Android virtual keyboard.

However non work correctly when working in landscape mode. Even if you manage to get the top of the memo visible, changing line will render the control out of sight, or you try and stay with the caret position and find the offset is wrong, manually correcting this causes issues with different resolutions.

Is there any article / component / code example, that anyone has seen, which solves this problem. I would opine that something so simple should be already resolved in the examples with RAD Studio, but alas it is not.

I am using native controls but am more than happy to switch back to Firemonkey styled controls if required.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What native controls are you using ? can you add some screenshot showing your problem ? i have maybe the solution for you ...